# Puppeteer headless mode unable to play video in full screen

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to play the video in full screen with the code below but it only works when the `headless` argument is set to false which means it cannot work on headless mode

Here is the code trying to play the youtube video on full-screen mode

The code below does click the full-screen button but the video still not playing in full-screen

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
        headless: true, 
        args: ['--start-maximized', '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:1080'],
        userDataDir: './userData',
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"]
    })
const page = await browser.newPage()
let currentScreen = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
        width: window.screen.availWidth,
        height: window.screen.availHeight,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1
    };
});

await page.setViewport(currentScreen);
await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36')
await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS2nNhqnKcQ');
await page.hover('.ytp-fullscreen-button')
await page.waitForTimeout(500)
await page.click('.ytp-fullscreen-button')
await page.screenshot({path: 'youtube.png'})
```

by the way, it cannot play video in full-screen on pornhub.com too

Comment: by the way, I am using manjaro operation system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, simply just change the `headless: true` to `headless: 'chrome'`

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8819#issuecomment-1223667718